# .How to uninstall older version of npm manually from the windows for create-react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

1. How do I fix the issue manually because nothing else works
2. After Executing the `create-react-app`.It does not give me the proper file structure or files themselves

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 0):

Update create-react-app

```
npm install -g create-react-app
/* yarn add global create-react-app */
```

or

I recommend using [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx).

```
npm install -g npx
/* yarn add global npx */
```

you can use some lastest version of products without install.

```
npx create-react-app ./my_react_app
```

Comment: Even with the solution mentioned above Iam running into this problem